# Specify pentaho logging level in command line

Tags: pentaho

When we run a Pentaho transformation (.ktr file) by directly invoking the .ktr file through a shell script, is there a way to specify the logging level (basic/Minimal) etc? What is the default?

Comment: Have you read the Pan/Kitchen [documentation](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Pan+User+Documentation)? Logging level is a parameter to these.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the Pan documentation:

"Set the logging level

**-level=Logging Level**

The level option sets the log level for the transformation that's being run.
These are the possible values:

**Error**: Only show errors

**Nothing**: Do not record any logging output.

**Minimal**: Only use minimal logging

**Basic**: This is the default basic logging level

**Detailed**: Give detailed logging output

**Debug**: For debugging purposes, very detailed output.

**Rowlevel**: Logging at a row level, this can generate a lot of data."

See also the documentation: [PDI Logging](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.1/Setup/Administration/Performance_Monitoring/Enable_Logging)